# Groovy Writable Object?

Tags: groovy, writable

Have a SimpleTemplate class that returns a Writable object. Can this be done as i can't see what kind of object to return. I have tried someting like this:

```
  Writable getTemplate()  { return 'something that's a writable' }
```

and how would i read variable from another method ?

Answer (score 1):

You could [do this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#asWritable%28%29) to return some writable string content:

```
Writable getTemplate() {
    { it.println "Some content" }.asWritable()
}
```